# Как как передать в `git push` логин и пароль?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

Обычно стоит противоположная задача - "Как не вводить каждый раз логин и пароль" при `git push`? Мне же нужно как раз наоборот. Как передать логин и пароль от аккаунта на GitHub в команду `os.system("git push ...")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Репозиторий можно передавать явно (а не использовать из конфига, [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)):

`git push https://user:password@github.com/repo/repo.git master`

Спец. символы в пароле нужно экранировать, например: `@` -> `\@`.

Если включена двухфакторная аутентификация, то такой способ работать не будет.